# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Webazon\Yoomoney\new\stdClass() на php

Tags: php, яндекс-касса

Пытался вручную отправить запрос на авторизацию юмани, не вышло, скачал библиотеку, выводит эту ошибку. Помогите пожалуйста, бьюсь уже 4 дня.
Ставил через компосер `composer require webazon/yoomoney`
`composer update` было
Ошибка в этой строке
`$res=new\stdClass();`

Comment: предположу, что у вас 8 версия php, а библиотека работает только под 7 версией. Нужен пробел, чтобы получилась следующая строка `$res=new \stdClass();`.

Comment: @ArchDemon Я бы предположил, что пробел здесь: `$res=new\ stdClass();`

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответы, правда, произошел конфликт версий, `$res=new \stdClass();`